# I want to write in LaTeX, but my co-authors do not

Tags: msword, collaboration, word-to-latex, latex-to-word

I prefer to write my academic papers in LaTeX whenever I am the main author. But my next upcoming paper requires more intricate back-and-forth collaboration with my co-authors. They do not like that I will be writing in tex as they prefer (or only knows) using MS Word.

Is there any convenient workaround that allows me to use LaTeX for editing (I use Overleaf - but can change if needed) while my three co-authors use Word?

PS. The work will involve working on same sections of the paper also, so we cannot simply split it into pieces where I would do my piece in LaTeX.

Thanks.

Comment: Related question on Academia.SE: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44981/collaborative-paper-writing-with-non-latex-using-colleagues where, among other solutions, the WYSIWYG LaTeX-editor LyX is mentioned. Another solution is to write everything in Word collaboratively, do not pay attention to mark-up or math formatting, and in the end you rewrite the paper in LaTeX.

Comment: While we can't close as a duplicate of a question on academia.se, it's about as close as duplicates get to the quesion @Marijn linked

Comment: I believe people have used [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) successfully to manage situations like these.  It has good support for LaTeX-style equations and deals with edit proposals in the docx document. Tables can become a problem though (no colspan).

Comment: It's common for people to be too lazy to learn to use a superior piece of technology (I mean you only have to learn it once to use it for the rest of your academic career...). If they're sufficiently technologically illiterate that they insist on using Word instead of LaTeX, then they probably wouldn't take advantage of LaTeX's full functionality anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main Question is, Are you using any of the advanced features of LaTeX?

If you are, Let them work in whatever editor they like. But tell your co-authors you expect plain TXT (text) files. That way the editor does not matter and its only a matter of merging in there text into the LaTeX source files.

If you are not. There is no real advantage of using Technology 'Y'. Just use whatever the group is comfortable in using.

Pro tip: Word Processors like Microsoft Word have a tendency to make you spend a lot of time in markup. While most of the time this is not important to the story being told (or paper being written)

I would advise to take a step back and focus on the product (the paper) and do the markup and lay outing after the text is written. this aves a lot of time an is technology agnostic.

For this purpose I would use (as in myself) a Markdown Editor like Atom, and a Git repository for concurrent Versioning. I must add that I am both familiar with git and markdown as an Software Developer.

Good luck with your papers.

--Additional:
 When you want to work together and edit the same files anywhere and not want 'merge-hell' use the tools Software developers have created. Tools like Git, Hg (Mercury), bzr (Bazaar) are all suitable for merging in edits from many developers into the same files.

Comment: You should add that merging with version control tools like git requires the usage of text files (which is what LaTeX code is stored in), not mutilated zip files (which is what MS word files are; seriously!).

Comment: @UTF-8 That is why I don't consider word to be a suitable format for collaboration. I would say the onus is on the word proponents to suggest a solution for that problem.

Comment: In Word you can use the draft mode to avoid decorations

Answer (score 31):

As a working scientist, I can answer: no, please do not focus on tricky solutions.

First of all, you are going to write a paper, and I guess you will send it to a journal for possible publication. So you should not start a religion war to use a piece of software that will be totally irrelevant for the final purpose. Unless, of course, the journal needs a specific file type for submission.

Second, it is mostly a matter of taste if you prefer TeX or Microsoft Word (or any other visual word processor). Both communities can spend plenty of words to convince the world that they are the best, but in my experience no scientist really needs the power of one system instead of the power of the other. Paradoxically, you could just write the paper by hand, and save time for more important discussions.

To summarize: vote and accept the majority. It will not be a big problem, if you have to write your paper with Word.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're the one responsible for the equations, citiations and cross-referencing, giving in to their preference costs you a huge amount of work to save them a small amount (hence [my answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/45007/8494) to the related question)

Comment: “ it is mostly a matter of taste if you prefer TeX or Microsoft Word” — No. For paper editing that’s just patently false: MS Word has numerous substantial drawbacks in this regard (to name just two: collaborative editing, and versioning). Agreed with the rest of the answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm by absolutely no standard a Window supporter, but what you wrote is wrong: (modern versions of) Word **do** support [collaborate editing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collaborate-on-Word-documents-with-real-time-co-authoring-7dd3040c-3f30-4fdd-bab0-8586492a1f1d) ([even in real time!](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Simultaneously-edit-a-document-with-other-authors-2a6059e7-9fe9-4e66-8ecd-f3d5372c27f4)) and [versioning](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/microsoft-word-for-teams/lesson5/). So I believe **it is** a matter of taste / knowledge / habits.

Comment: @Clément I’m aware of their “collaborative editing” feature, having had to use it extensively. Prior to the latest version, these features were rather lacking compared to the state of the art in collaborative editing. It still required manually merging documents that had been simultaneously edited. I can’t judge the latest version: maybe Word has caught up to the state of the art now.

Comment: In my case, it would be a big problem to use Word.  A) I don't use Windows, and B) I'm dysiconic, and so have real problems trying to use any icon-driven interface.

Comment: @jamesqf Is that your own personal term? I can't seem to find another usage of dysiconic that isn't by you.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I interpret the point made in the answer (“no scientist really needs the power of one system instead of…”) as: it is mostly a matter of taste whether you consider poorer support (assuming that's the case) for features like “collaborative editing” and “versioning” as “substantial drawbacks” or not. Those features and power are nice to have and we can get used to them (similarly Word users can get used to doing things a certain way that they can't with LaTeX), but they are merely conveniences; we can manage without them: people did manage when writing papers by hand with pen.

Comment: @jamesqf You might find it useful to learn the Alt codes. You can press Alt then type letters to access every single function.

Comment: @JAB he coined the word.

Comment: @KonradRudolph surely industries also need collaborative editing and versioning, right?

Comment: @JAB: Yes, I coined the term (though others may have used it before me) by analogy to dyslexia, in order to describe the problems I have figuring out what those !$#&@ little "intuitive" pictures are supposed to mean.  WRT alt-codes, it might be useful if I ever again have to deal with a Windows environment.  Fortunately, that's unlikely.

Comment: @jamesqf - not everything is pathological.

Comment: <del>It's easy.</del> A blank piece of paper is New Document; a blank piece of paper with a star in the corner is New Document from Template; a floppy disk is Save; a floppy disk with a star in the corner is Save As; an anticlockwise arrow starting from the bottom and going 3/4 of the way 'round is Redo; an anticlockwise arrow starting from the top and going all the way 'round is Repeat. It's hard. :-/

Answer (score 6):

I've been doing this lately, and my solution has been to do the work in LaTeX but compile in multiple formats including .docx.

This allows collaborators to use the format they feel comfortable in, but still lets me use my preferred system for writing. The downside is that it requires you to manually port their changes from the format they were working on into the tex document. When the changes are moderate, this is not too bad, but it can get to be a lot if they are making large changes.

This has been driven by the fact that my collaborators are non-technical, but the documents themselves have a lot of technical features. I am unwilling to give up the power of my system (RMarkdown, LaTeX, and Git). However, there is also no way that these collaborators will (or should) invest the time to learn Git or LaTeX.

Comment: If you're going to answer like this, shouldn't you be sharing your workflow to compile to docx?

Comment: I interpret "how should/could I approach this problem?" as a distinct problem from "how do I execute strategy X?" There are a lot of ways to convert to docx format, each has drawbacks. While I tend to use pandoc, it may be easier to do something else for the OP (particularly if ze is using complex packages).

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do this several times. So far, the easiest is simply to make a copy of the tex file and change the filename so that it has a txt extension. I circulate that and a pdf of the paper (so that tables and figures are available). My co-authors simply ignore all the formatting instructions and use the Microsoft Word 'track changes' feature on the bits they are writing. I then accept the changes that I want and copy the fixed text back into the LaTeX master.

This workflow assumes the LaTeX user is not just the main author, but really preparing most of the document with the others editing, commenting and perhaps writing some paragraphs.